# Trying to calculate amount of occurrences in a list grouped

Tags: python, list, intervals

I'm trying to count the amount of 1's in a list that occurs after each other.

```
data = [0,4,5,2,-1,-2,5,1,5,3,5]

count = 0
count_list = []
new_count_list = []

for i in data:
    if i > 0:
        count_list.append(1)
    elif i <= 0:
        count_list.append(0)

for number in count_list:
    if number == 0:
        new_count_list.append(count)
        count = 0
    elif number == 1:
        count = count+1

print(count_list)
print(new_count_list)
```

For some reason the output is only showing:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Can you explain more what do you want exactly ?
What is the difference between count_list and new_count_list?

Comment: `1, 1, 1` are consecutive that's why count gets 3. What is actually your expectation?

Comment: I initially wanted to make a program that would count the number of positive numbers before a negative one, in order to find the average amount of positive numbers before a negative occurring. I just change the numbers into ones and zeros in order for simplicity. So the 3 in new_count_list is 3 occurrences before a negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, in the second for loop, new_count_list is updated only when it sees a zero in count_list. Now, since there are 3 zeroes in count_list, 3 entries are there in new_count_list. Final value of count is not updated to the new_count_list. So you just need to append final value of count to new_count_list after the second for loop to get the desired result.
`new_count_list.append(count)`
Add this after the second for loop.. Then the output will be
[0, 3, 0, 5]

Comment: Shouldnt the output be `[0, 3,0,0,5]`?

Comment: @adirabargil Nope. After looping through 3 ones, count will get incremented to 3. Then when it encounters first zero, 3 will be appended to list and count becomes zero. When it encounter second zero in a row, 0 will be appended to the list. Then it will never encounter a zero, and hence nothing will be written to the list. Finally when the loop ends, then 5 will be written into the list. So after 3, there will only be one 0 followed by 5.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to count 1's in a row in your `count_list`. The reason why you don't get `[0,3,0,5]` is because you only happend to `new_count_list` if your current number is 0.

The last row of 5 1's is therefore not taken into account because it does not end with a 0.

You just have to add a new test at the end of the loop.

Furthermore, there is no need to build the `count_list`, you can just test wether the number is positive or negative.

Comment: Ahh, I get you. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

In case if `1` is last element of your `list` `count` is not `.appended`. I want point that I would harness certain python's features to do this task in less lines of code. Namely:

```
import itertools
data = [0,4,5,2,-1,-2,5,1,5,3,5]
data_1 = [1 if i>0 else 0 for i in data]
out = [sum(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(data_1)]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 0, 5]
```

Explanation: I used list comprehension with ternary if and then [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to create group, which values I `sum`med.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve directly what you want by using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) that will do the grouping for you:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [0,4,5,2,-1,-2,5,1,5,3,5]

lengths = [(len(list(group)), is_positive) for is_positive, group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x>0)]

# [(1, False), (3, True), (2, False), (5, True)]

out = [length for length, is_positive in lengths if is_positive]
print(out)
# [3, 5]
```

The condition for grouping is that the value is positive. For each group, we keep a tuple with the length of the group, and the key, which tells us if this is a group of positive values.

Then, we just filter the groups of positive values.